# How to modify the background transparency of NavigationBar in Compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I want to modify the background color transparency of `NavigationBar`, but the above code doesn't work.

```kotlin
       NavigationBar(
            modifier = Modifier.background(Color.Transparent),
            tonalElevation = 0.dp,
            containerColor = colorScheme.secondaryContainer.copy(0.7f),
            contentColor = colorScheme.primary) {
       }
```

Comment: Can you post a screen of the expected result?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti I need a translucent `NavigationBar `, sorry I don't have a rendering

Comment: Should work, tonal elevation only works if container color is MaterialTheme.colors.surface, so it is irrelevant as much as the background in modifier. Maybe you have someting inside the navigationbar that has some background